# Type caste Serilog in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asp.net-core

```
 public class WorkletSelectionForm : Form
 {  
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public WorkletSelectionForm( ILogger<WorkletSelectionForm> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        private void btnClick_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            MainForm _frm = new MainForm((ILogger<MainForm>)_logger);
        }
 }
```

**Getting TypeCaste Run-Time Error: Cann't convert ILogger< WorkletSelectionForm> to ILogger< MainForm>**

Comment: Creating a new MainForm already smells. You shouldn't need to do that in the first place. Therefore, I am suspecting an x-y, here.

Comment: But outside above mentioned issue, if this was legit, you could inject an `ILoggerFactory` and use that to fetch the appropriate logger types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to inject the `ILogger<MainForm>` into the constructor as well, these types and instances are not interchangable.

Try this

```
public class WorkletSelectionForm : Form
     {  
            private readonly ILogger _logger;
            private readonly ILogger<MainForm> _mainFormLogger;
    
            public WorkletSelectionForm(
                ILogger<WorkletSelectionForm> logger,
                ILogger<MainForm> mainFormLogger)
            {
                _logger = logger;
                _mainFormLogger = mainFormLogger;
            }
    
            private void btnClick_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                MainForm _frm = new MainForm(_mainFormLogger);
            }
     }
```